# ORDER BY CASE not behaving correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by, case

I have a puzzling issue with ORDER BY CASE:

I wrote a test proc with a VARCHAR(50) parameter "sortBy":

```
BEGIN

SELECT N.Num_Of_Users, N.Noun_Created FROM NOUNS N 
ORDER BY CASE sortBy
    WHEN 'numReviews' THEN Num_Of_Users 
     ELSE Noun_Created END DESC;
END
```

If I call this proc with anything but the varchar 'numReviews' it sorts by Noun_Created as expected, but if I call it with 'numReviews' it does not sort at all.

Confused by this I hard coded the sort to:

```
BEGIN
SELECT N.Num_Of_Users, N.Noun_Created FROM NOUNS N 
ORDER BY Num_Of_Users;
END
```

and it sorts correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `Num_Of_Users` and `Noun_Created` have different types.  So, the SQL engine ends up doing a type conversion (typically to a string) -- and you do not get the results you expect.

That is why it is better to use separate `case` statements when setting keys for the `order by`.  Try this:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN sortBy = 'numReviews' THEN Num_Of_Users END),
         (CASE WHEN sortBy = 'numReviews' THEN NULL ELSE Noun_Created END) DESC;
```

If you have only one choice, the second `case` is not necessary.  You can just use:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN sortBy = 'numReviews' THEN Num_Of_Users END),
         Noun_Created
```

Comment: Why does it matter that they are different types?

Comment: Because the `case` statement returns a single value with a well-defined type.  If the `when` clauses are of different types, some value needs to be converted to some other value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data types of the two columns are different - one is numeric, while the other one is a string. This may lead to some confusion when sorting.

Try this approach instead:

```
BEGIN

SELECT N.Num_Of_Users, N.Noun_Created FROM NOUNS N 
ORDER BY CASE sortBy  WHEN 'numReviews' END DESC,
         CASE WHEN sortBy <> 'numReviews' THEN Num_Of_Users END DESC
END
```